# Maintaining OneToMany links with a form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Imagine these 2 entities

```
Intervention
    - items        # OneToMany (no cascade)
    addItem()
    removeItem()

Item
    - intervention # ManyToOne
```

When I'm doing an `Intervention` I want to select the `Items` concerned.

I use an `Intervention` form in which I can attach/unattach items

```
->add('items', EntityIdType::class, array(
    'class' => Item::class,
    'multiple' => true,
))
```

When the form is submitted, I see Doctrine calls my `Intervention`'s `addItem()`, `removeItem()`

But when I empty any previously attached items (thus sending `null` as `items`), Doctrine tells me:

> Neither the property "items" nor one of the methods "addItem()"/"removeItem()", "setItems()", "items()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Intervention".

The first question is: **Why Doctrine is not finding my accessors when I send a `null` item list ?**

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for now is to implement a `setItems()` doing the adds/removes:

```
/**
 * Set items
 *
 * @param $items
 *
 * @return Intervention
 */
public function setItems($items)
{
    foreach ($this->items as $item) {
        $this->removeItem($item);
    }
    if ($items) {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->addItem($item);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `ArrayCollection` in your other side of the `ManyToOne` relationship.
Your `AppBundle\Entity\Item` entity class needs to have:

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Intervention;
//...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Intervention", inverseBy="items")
 */
private $intervention;

/**
 * @param Intervention $intervention
 */
public function setIntervention(Intervention $intervention){
    $this->intervention = $intervention;
}

/**
 * @return Intervention
 */
public function getIntervention(){
    return $this->intervention;
}
```

Then in the `AppBundle\Entity\Intervention` entity class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
//...

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", mappedBy="intervention")
 */
private $items;

public function __construct(){
    $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getItems(){
    return $this->items;
}

public function setItems($items){
    $this->items = $items;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did at the beginning, but the `Item` accessors are not triggered, so they are never linked to the intervention.

Comment: This means you have other problem, as the relationship is set correctly.